# Apache - can't create new access.log file in var/log/httpd/site folder

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

I have an old `access.log` file that weight about 20gb.
I want to create a new file that will replace the old one.
What I did was name the old file from `access.log` to `access-old.log` and created a new one named `access.log`. I have noticed that the `access-old.log` keeps increasing and the new file gets no effect.

How can I configure the the new file to contain the access logs from the site?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do in order that the new files will take effect was to restart the apache.

```
service httpd restart
```

I didnt even had to manually create new files, the apache creates them by him self